# Check incomplete video segment with ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, codec

I have a user who has a very large video that they have to upload: it is at least 100GB and of the `.mov` format. I need to check the following before the user is able to upload the full file:

- Has resolution 1920x080
- Has video codec Apple ProRes 422
- Has either 6 or 8 audio tracks
- Has PCM Little Endian audio

I have thought of the following approaches in order to check if the user has a valid file for uploading:

- Perhaps grab only the first 10K bytes of the file and check the header (would this always work?)
- Grab perhaps 10K of the head and 10K of the tail and run ffmpeg of that (either server-side or on in-browser via https://itnext.io/build-ffmpeg-webassembly-version-ffmpeg-js-part-1-preparation-ed12bf4c8fac).

What might be a good approach to do this? Again, to repeat, I have a user uploading a very large video and I want to pre-check that it meets four criteria before allowing them to upload the entire video file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FFmpeg needs to parse the full header and first few frames of every video/audio stream to fill in these details. You'll probably need lot more than 10K for the header, say 1M.
And depending on where the `moov` is, you'll need data from both the  head and tail.

It'll be more convenient for the user to visit https://mediaarea.net/MediaInfoOnline and send you the text report.

Comment: cool! That seems to be the second approach and they've already done the hard stuff -- compiling it to wasm: https://mediaarea.net/_/js/MediaInfoWasm-20.03.wasm.